# Confusion of column count for tree views

Tags: c++, qt

In the following example, every child item has only 1 column although it is supposed to have 2 columns.

( MyTreeModel is a subclass of QAbstractItemModel. )

```
int MyTreeModel::columnCount( const QModelIndex &rParent /*= QModelIndex()*/ ) const
{
    if (rParent.isValid())
    {
           return 2;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

In the following example, QTreeView show 2 columns for parent items and 1 column for child items as expected.

```
int MyTreeModel::columnCount( const QModelIndex &rParent /*= QModelIndex()*/ ) const
{
    if (rParent.isValid())
    {
           return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

So, it seems that the column number of child items is limited by the column number of its parent item. Is it the standard behavior ? Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: I'm guessing that `QTreeView` detects required number of columns based on root item values. It can't traverse whole tree to detect column count for performance reasons. Best way to verify it is take a pick on source code of `QTreeView`.

Comment: @MarekR is 100% right. Column count is calculated only for root items. If you need less columns in any row - simply don't fill them and return invalid QModelIndex in ::index

Comment: @Marek R It does traverse whole tree to detect column count (I checked it using break points). But it does not call the data(..) function in MyTreeModel for columns greater than the parent's number of columns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked the source code at https://qt.gitorious.org/ (currently not working alternative https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/blob/dev/src/widgets/) and found the answer as follows:

1. I checked the method [`void QTreeView::setModel(QAbstractItemModel *model)`](https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/blob/dev/src/widgets/itemviews/qtreeview.cpp#L213-319). There I noticed line `d->header->setModel(model);`. Header is what you need.
2. [Type of header](https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/blob/dev/src/widgets/itemviews/qtreeview_p.h#L174), it is `QHeaderView`.
3. Then I checked the method [`void QHeaderView::setModel(QAbstractItemModel *model)`](https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/blob/dev/src/widgets/itemviews/qheaderview.cpp#L342)
4. There connection is made:  `QObject::disconnect(d->model, SIGNAL(columnsInserted(QModelIndex,int,int)), this, SLOT(sectionsInserted(QModelIndex,int,int)));`
5. The last thing I did was read the slot method [`void QHeaderView::sectionsInserted(const QModelIndex &parent, int logicalFirst, int logicalLast)`](https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/blob/dev/src/widgets/itemviews/qheaderview.cpp#L1820)

Guess what I've found there:

```
void QHeaderView::sectionsInserted(const QModelIndex &parent,
int logicalFirst, int logicalLast)
{
    Q_D(QHeaderView);
    if (parent != d->root)
        return; // we only handle changes in the top level
```

So only top level items have impact on number of columns.

Comment: updated location: https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/blob/dev/src/widgets/itemviews/qheaderview.cpp#L1826